# Given holomorphic map $f:M\to Gr(N,k)$, is it possible to make sure $\exists B\in Gr(N,k), f(M)\cap\Sigma_B=\emptyset$?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $f:M\to Gr(N,k)$ be a holomorphic map where $M$ is an algebraic curve(i.e. closed compact Riemann surface) and $Gr(N,k)$ is gramssmanian of $k+1$ plane space in $C^{N+1}$ with $C$ being complex number.

Let $B$ be an $k+1$ plane of $C^{N+1}$ represented by an exterior algebra element. Then from inner product $(-,-)$ on exterior algebra induced from $C^{N+1}$ standard inner product, one can define $\Sigma_B=\{\Lambda\in Gr(N,k)\vert (B,\Lambda)=0\}$ which clearly defines codimension 1 subvariety of $Gr(N,k)$.

"Let $f:M\to Gr(N,k)$ be a holomoprhic curve s.t. the image $f(M)$ does not belong to $\Sigma_B$."

$\textbf{Q:}$ Is it possible always to choose a $B$ s.t. $f(M)\cap\Sigma_B=\emptyset$? $f(M)$ should be at most dimension 1. However $\Sigma_B$ is codimension 1. The intersection is possible to be non-empty from dimension counting of component of intersection dimension$\geq 1+(n-1)-n=0$ where I have assumed $f(M)$ smooth image. How to find existence of such $B$, if possible?

Ref. Chern, Complex Manifolds without Potential Theory pg 84, Sec 9 right around equation (9.3)

Comment: The intersection of all the $\Sigma_B$ is empty, and in particular they don't all contain $f(M)$.

Comment: ^ I might be confused, despite the confident phrasing.

Comment: @hunter I am more confused by your statement. Do you mean there is a $B$ s.t. $f(M)\cap\Sigma_B=\emptyset$ or do you mean $f(M)\not\subset\Sigma_B$? It is clear that $f(M)$ can't avoid all $\Sigma_B$ if you run through $Gr(N,k)$. Since $\Sigma_B$ is a hypersurface in $Gr(N,k)$. Certainly, $f(M)\cap\Sigma_B$ will have dimension at most $0$ as it is image of a curve. Thus the question is whether it is possible to have no intersection at all.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question as the much easier $\neq \emptyset$! My mistake.

Comment: oh I see why, the quotation you are quoting says we just don't wnat it to be contained in $\Sigma_B$, not that we want it to miss $\Sigma_B$ altogether, right?

Comment: I think the question as stated is false, e.g. if $M$ is just a curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$ then it doesn't miss any lines.

Comment: @hunter Yep. It is false for $P^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the comments:

I think the question as stated is false, e.g. if $M$ is just a curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$ then it doesn't miss any lines. But I think that the quotation you are copying is just saying that we can choose $B$ such that $f(M)$ is not entirely contained in $B$, not saying that we can choose $B$ such that $f(M)$ misses $B$.